# Django Show var as Label name

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    telefoon = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    telefoon_mobiel = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    woonplaats = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=True)
    straat = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

form.py

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    straat = forms.CharField(required=False,
                             widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    postcode = forms.CharField(required=False,
                         widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    woonplaats = forms.CharField(required=False,
                         widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    telefoon = forms.CharField(required=False,
                         widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    telefoon_mobiel = forms.CharField(required=False,
                         widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('telefoon', 'telefoon_mobiel', 'woonplaats', 'postcode', 'straat')
```

views.py

```
@login_required
@transaction.atomic
def profiel(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request, ('Profiel aangepast'))
            return redirect('user')
        else:
            messages.error(request, ('Los ondestaande probleem op'))
    else:
        user_form = UserForm(instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    
    
    return render(request, 'public/profiel.html', {
        'user_form': user_form,
        'profile_form': profile_form,
    })
```

template:

```
<div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Profiel {{ user.get_full_name }}</h5>
                <hr>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            {{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            {{ straat }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <label>Achternaam:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            {{ user_form.last_name }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

When I call for example the field `straat` I am getting an *editable field* and I just want to show the *value of it as text*.

Comment: You're not passing the variable `straat` to your template, but you're using it. Where does it come from?

Comment: If you need to show a kind of "profile page preview", not an edit form, then _don't render a form_. Make another read-only template, view, url pattern.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.